# webcam on chrome. Until yesterday it worked (months), not today, what happened?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, webcam

This code was working until yesterday for months without problems, but today it has stopped working. I suspect that google has stopped admitting some code, but I do not know which one.

Chrome does not show me any code error.

```js
//<![CDATA[
window.onload=function(){
navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia;

window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL || window.mozURL || window.msURL;

var start = document.querySelector('#start'),
    capture = document.querySelector('#capture'),
    canvas = document.querySelector('canvas'),
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
    video = document.querySelector('video');

start.addEventListener('click', function () {

    navigator.getUserMedia({
      video: true
    }, function (stream) {
      var src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
      video.src = src;
    }, function (e) {
      console.log(e);
    });

 

}, false);

   capture.addEventListener('click', function () {
      ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    }, false);
}//]]>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title></title>

</head>

<body>

<video autoplay></video>
<canvas width="300" height="200"></canvas>
    <button id="start">Start</button>
<button id="capture">Capture</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried other browser ?

Comment: If you're not using a `https://` or a `localhost`, Chrome won't let the script access the webcam.

Comment: Yes, I tried other browser, same problem. I use https://. By the moment the code work if move the script code into the body tags, but in this case other script (geolocalization) dont work. Very strange.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem as follows:

I Change " window.onload=function(){ " for  " function webcam(){ " and then I call the function from the " onload" in the body tag.

Now all work again.

But i don't understand why.